# VS2017 Outlining Indentation Is Off After Aurelia CLI New

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aurelia

I have a project in VS2017.  When I first created the project, the editor would automatically indent my next line of code appropriately.

However, I ran the Aurelia CLI command `au new --here` and selected WebPack as my module loader and ASP.NET Core as my target platform.  Everything seemed to go well, but now, anytime I edit a file, the indenting is off -- everything winds up getting "out-dented" rather than "in-dented".

[image]

In this image, I had placed my cursor on the inside of the `{` and hit enter.  Notice the cursor position.  Rather than being 3 or 5 spaces inside the braces of the `OnGet` method, the cursor winds up 3 or 5 spaces outside.

Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that Aurelia CLI adds a file called .editorconfig to the project.  I simply deleted that file and things seem to be working correctly now.